# Scrolling back to top of listvview

Tags: android, android-listview, onscroll

I have a list view that retrieves data from parse.com. I have added onscroll listener to load the list items after every 15 items. It's working fine but when the whole list is loaded and when we want to scroll back to the top the scrolling is not smooth its like moving up and down. To better understand my problem  [watch this video](https://youtu.be/598puWiNWY8)

My code

```
public class InterActivity extends Activity 
{


ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
FinalAdapter adapter;
 List<CodeList> codelist = null;
 SharedPreference shrdPreference;

 private int limit = 15;


View footerView;






@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inter_layout);
    shrdPreference = new SharedPreference();



    //Execute RemoteDataTask AsyncTask

    new RemoteDataTask().execute();
}

private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(InterActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Please wait loading ...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array
        codelist = new ArrayList<CodeList>();
        try {
            // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "InterActivity");
            // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
            // by ascending
            query.orderByAscending("_created_at");
            query.setLimit(limit);
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject inter : ob) {


                map.setIntroduction((String) inter.get("intro"));
                map.setFinalCodeText((String) inter.get("codetext"));


                codelist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.inter_layoutListView);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new FinalAdapter(InterActivity.this,
                                      codelist);

    //  AlphaInAnimationAdapter animationAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(adapter);
    //  animationAdapter.setAbsListView(listview);



        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        //listview.setOnItemClickListener(InterActivity.this);

        //listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(InterActivity.this); 
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                                                 int scrollState) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int threshold = 1;
                    int count = listview.getCount();

                    if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                        if (listview.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count
                            - threshold) {
                            // Execute LoadMoreDataTask AsyncTask
                            new Loadmore().execute();
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                                     int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });




    }
}


private class Loadmore extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(InterActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("load More Tutorial");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading more...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array
        codelist = new ArrayList<CodeList>();
        try {
            // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "InterActivity");
            // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
            // by ascending
            query.orderByAscending("_created_at");
            query.setLimit(limit += 15);
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject inter : ob) {

                ParseFile listpic = (ParseFile) inter.get("alphabetimg");
                ParseFile levelpic = (ParseFile) inter.get("levelimg");
                ParseFile apipic = (ParseFile) inter.get("apiimg");
                ParseFile descpicone = (ParseFile) inter.get("descimgone");
                ParseFile descpictwo = (ParseFile) inter.get("descimgtwo");
                ParseFile videopic = (ParseFile) inter.get("videoimg");
                ParseFile hashtagpic = (ParseFile) inter.get("hashimg");
                ParseFile video = (ParseFile) inter.get("demovideo");

                //      ParseFile downloadfile = (ParseFile) inter.get("download");

                CodeList map = new CodeList();

                map.setIntroduction((String) inter.get("intro"));
                map.setFinalCodeText((String) inter.get("codetext"));



                codelist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        int position = listview.getLastVisiblePosition();
        adapter = new FinalAdapter(InterActivity.this,
                                   codelist);


        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        listview.setSelectionFromTop(position, 0);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: cant see video says file does not exist

Comment: @Virus Will upload it again

Comment: Try using OnTouchListener instead of OnScrollListener - check my answer

Comment: @Virus Yes doing it Now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not recreate the list and the adapter each time you load more data. Replace the LoadMore class by this one:

```
private class Loadmore extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(InterActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("load More Tutorial");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading more...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array
        codelist.clear();
        try {
            // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "InterActivity");
            // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
            // by ascending
            query.orderByAscending("_created_at");
            query.setLimit(limit += 15);
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject inter : ob) {

                ParseFile listpic = (ParseFile) inter.get("alphabetimg");
                ParseFile levelpic = (ParseFile) inter.get("levelimg");
                ParseFile apipic = (ParseFile) inter.get("apiimg");
                ParseFile descpicone = (ParseFile) inter.get("descimgone");
                ParseFile descpictwo = (ParseFile) inter.get("descimgtwo");
                ParseFile videopic = (ParseFile) inter.get("videoimg");
                ParseFile hashtagpic = (ParseFile) inter.get("hashimg");
                ParseFile video = (ParseFile) inter.get("demovideo");

                //      ParseFile downloadfile = (ParseFile) inter.get("download");

                CodeList map = new CodeList();

                map.setIntroduction((String) inter.get("intro"));
                map.setFinalCodeText((String) inter.get("codetext"));

                codelist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        int position = listview.getLastVisiblePosition();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        listview.setSelectionFromTop(position, 0);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Tell me :)

Comment: I have edited the video link and posted a working one please have a look . if the problem is with what you said how shall I change it. Please help me thank you

Comment: Tried it removed recreation of adapter and added adapter.notifydatasetchanged() as you said.  But now the list only loads fist 15 items

Comment: Did you add this line too? adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); inside the protected void onPostExecute(Void result) method ?

Comment: Yeah added that line also

Comment: No where shall I add it

Comment: Inside the protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) method of your Loadmore class. (you just had to copy my answer :) but no problem)

Comment: Replace **codelist = new ArrayList<CodeList>();** by **codelist.clear();** inside the Loadmore class.

Comment: Yeah will do it right now and inform you. Thanks for being patient

Comment: Everything works fine but even after reaching the complete end of the list it still loads how to stop this from happening

Answer (score 0):

Try using `OnTouchListener` instead of `OnScrollListener` (this will help you detect the scroll direction in a easier fashion and react accordingly):

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            float height;
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                float height = event.getY();

                int action = event.getAction();
                int threshold = 1;
                int count = listview.getCount();

                if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    // do nothing
                    this.height = height;
                }else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

                     if(this.height < height){
                         Log.v(TAG, "Scrolled up");
                         // do nothing - user is going up
                     }else if(this.height > height){
                         Log.v(TAG, "Scrolled down");
                         //execute LoadMore Task
                         if (listview.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count
                            - threshold) {
                            // Execute LoadMoreDataTask AsyncTask
                            new Loadmore().execute();
                        }
                     }

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```